# A message in my inbox brought me to nowhere

Tags: bug, election, global-inbox

I just got a message in my inbox with this link:

https://stackoverflow.com/election/4#post-15075560

Well... that doesn't bring me to the message nor anywhere helpful.

Answer (score 4):

It is a link to https://stackoverflow.com/election/4?tab=nomination#post-15075560 but because the primary phase of the election has now started, the old link leads to the wrong tab.

You have a comment reply from Jeremy Banks on the nomination tab which triggered the inbox message.

You need to load all comments on the post the above link goes to, there doesn't seem to be a auto-open-comments link format for election posts like there is for comments on normal site posts.

Comment: +1, Your second hash link doesn't work at all. anyway it's still a bug.

Comment: @foo: That's because the comments are collapsed, figuring out how to trigger the auto-open.